# asynccontrols asp.net Error Creating Control " Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls, asynccontroller

here is my sample form. 
I'm using asynccontrols
. Site compiles fine, loads fine, works fine. Can't view anything in designer. Halp?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Calendar2.aspx.cs" Inherits="txssaAuction.Calendar2" %>
  <%@ Register Assembly="AsyncControls" Namespace="DelvingWare.AsyncControls" TagPrefix="dw" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>



 <dw:asynccalendar runat="server" ID="calMain"
 DefaultStyle="false" 
 AbbreviateDays="true"
 PreviousMonthText="&lt;div class='navPrev' title='Previous Month'>&lt;&lt;&lt;</div>"
 NextMonthText="<div class='navNext' title='Next Month'>&gt;&gt;&gt;</div>"
 SelectedDayCssClass="selDay" 
 CssClass="asyncCalReg"
 WeekendDayCssClass="weekend" 
 OtherMonthCssClass="otherMonth" 
 DayCssClass="calday" 
 Width="500"
 MonthListCssClass="monthList" 
 YearListCssClass="yearList" 
 TodayCssClass="today"
 TodayFooterCssClass="todayFooter"
 DaySelectionMode="Multiple" 
 OnDaySelected="calMain_DaySelected" 
 MonthSelectorCssClass="monthSelector"
 YearSelectorCssClass="yearSelector" />

 <p>
 <dw:asynclistbox runat="server" ID="lstMain"
 SelectionMode="Single"
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstMain_IndexChanged" 
 Rows="7">
    <AsyncListItem Text="No Selected Dates" Value="none" />
 </dw:asynclistbox>
 <br/>
 <dw:asynclinkbutton runat="server" ID="lnkMain" 
 ConfirmMessage="Are you sure you want to clear all selected dates?"
 OnClick="lnkMain_Click">Clear Selected Dates</dw:asynclinkbutton>
 </p>
    </p>
    <dw:AsyncRepeater ID="rptUsers" runat="server" 
        OnItemDataBound="rptUser_ItemDataBound"
        EnableEffects="true" 
        RollACssClass="rollA" 
        RollBCssClass="rollB" 
        HighlightCssClass="highlight"
        CssClass="asyncRep" 
        Visible="true">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="4">
                <tr class="headlnk">
                    <td>
                        First Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Last Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Account Balance
                    </td>
                </tr>            
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr $roll$ $highlight$>
                    <td>
                    <dw:AsyncLiteral runat="server" ID="ltlFirstName" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <dw:AsyncLiteral runat="server" ID="ltlLastName" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <dw:AsyncLiteral runat="server" ID="ltlAccBalance" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
            </FooterTemplate>

        </dw:AsyncRepeater>
<br />
<dw:AsyncButton runat="server" ID="btMain" 
OnClick="btMain_Click" 
CssClass="greyButton">Re-Bind the AsyncRepeater</dw:AsyncButton>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no, the error is only in the designer.

Comment: My Bad... thought the wrong thing!